# IronAHK in LinuxMint 12 Troubles

Tags: linux, autohotkey, linux-mint

I'm having trouble on Linux Mint 12

If I use a `Send` command and try to compile I get this:

```
Example.ahk (0): ==> Unable to change after type has been created. 
Compilation failed.
```

If I run from the terminal `ironahk Example.ahk` I get:

```
^[[E^[[17~^[[18~^[[D^[[18~^[[D ^[[E^[OR^[[D^[[E
```

for "This is a test"

This is the last thing keeping me from using Linux, and it's beyond me...

Comment: Please could you add the text of Example.ahk to your question?

Comment: It's just "Send This is a test"